# How to change default hover style of buttons from blue to yellow?

Tags: html, css

I want to change default hover blue style effect of the buttons to yellow if it's possible, but I didn't know how to do this.

Edit: Somothing like this http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/13/hoverbuttons.png/

Comment: I think this is JavaScript . Can you be more specific?

Comment: blue and yellow hover http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/13/hoverbuttons.png/

Answer (score 2):

## CSS

```
a.button:hover{
     background: #FFF;
}
```

Currently Supported by all Major Browsers

---

## Resources

**w3Schools**: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

**Aptana**: http://www.aptana.com/reference/html/api/CSS.element.Hover%20Link.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:hover` psuedo-class.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3Ahover